# Regular Expression to match file name

Tags: .net, regex

I trying to work out what regex will match filenames in quotes.  Eg.

```
blah blah rubarb "someFile.txt" blah
rubard "anotherFile.txt" blah blah
```

I would like to match

```
someFile.txt
anotherFile.txt
```

I'm using .NET. I am going through the documentation now but any help much appreciated.

Comment: Why use `Regex` for this? Looks like `string.Split` will work nicely.

Comment: Are you trying to do this: 'blah blah rubarb "someFile.txt" blah'.match(/("someFile.txt")/ig);

Comment: @Oded I would like to see the code :)

Comment: @the_joric - What? `myString.Split('"')[1]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will match non-whitespace characters plus 3-4 characters extension in file name.

```
\"(\S+\.\w{3,4})\"
```

Comment: @MylesMcDonnell - be aware that this regex includes the `"`'s in the match

Comment: @MylesMcDonnel it will also not match any files with extensions of 2 chars or more than 4 chars. So `myfile.cs` will not match and neither will `myfile.csproj`

Comment: To include files with at least 2 chars or 2 to n number of chars in extension, one can use `\w{2,}`. To include files with at least 1 char in extension, one can use `\w+`.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
(?<=")\w+\.\w+(?=")
```

This will not include the quotes in the match.

NOTE: I've made one assumption with this regex. I'm assuming the file name will only contain a single `.` character. So `my.file.txt` will not match. If you need that to match, let me know and i'll update it.

The following shows you how to use this in c# code to iterate over all the matches.

```
try {
    Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(?<="")\w+\.\w+(?="")");
    Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
    while (matchResults.Success) {
        // matched text: matchResults.Value
        // match start: matchResults.Index
        // match length: matchResults.Length
        matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
    } 
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

and here are some comments to help you understand it:

```
@"
(?<=    # Assert that the regex below can be matched, with the match ending at this position (positive lookbehind)
   ""       # Match the character “""” literally
)
\w      # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores)
   +       # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\.      # Match the character “.” literally
\w      # Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, and underscores)
   +       # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(?=     # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   ""       # Match the character “""” literally
)
"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
\"(\w+\.\w+)\"
```

**Hint :** Remember to escape `\`s...